# Doubly Linked List Insertion at first error C program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node{
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
    int value;
}node;

node* insert_first(node*head,int val){
    if (head==NULL){
        node *temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->prev=NULL;
        temp->next=NULL;
        head=temp;
    }
    else{
        node *temp=(node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->value=val;
        temp->prev=NULL;
        temp->next=head;
        head->prev=temp;
        head=temp;

    }
        return head;
}

void print_node(node *head){
    node *compteur = head;
    printf("list is :");
    while(compteur != NULL){
        printf("%d ",compteur->value);
        compteur = compteur->next;
    }
}

void main(){
    node *head =NULL;
    head = insert_first(head,1);


    print_node(head);
}
```

I'm trying to insert an element at the first position.
The code works when I try to insert 2 or more elements and they are printed (expect the first element).
I have a problem when I try to insert just 1 element and then print it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean by "I have a problem"? Is the compiler complaining? If so, what does it say? Or is the program not doing what it is supposed to be doing? If so, what is the expected behaviour vs the actual one?

Comment: You forgot `#include <stdlib.h>`, it's not `- >` but `->` (no space between `-` and `>`), `insert_first` doesn't return a value, and on the first line of `main`, you use `head` while it is not yet initialized, the `new_node` function is total nonsense and certainly a few more problems.

Comment: There are errors in 'insert_furst ()' and 'new_node ()' functions.Look what you do with the head pointer.

Comment: this is what i get after i edited all you guys told me to edit:
https://imgur.com/a/uUNhcMI

Comment: You don't assign a value in insert_first when head == null. You should add the line `temp->value=val;`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're defining the `node*` in the `struct` as `struct node*` ? Should just work with `node * prev` and `node * next`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in the below logic:

```
while (compteur != NULL) {
    compteur = compteur - > next;
    printf("%d ", compteur - > value);
  }
```

You are pointing the compteur to its next and then trying to print the value. It should be

```
while (compteur != NULL) {
    printf("%d ", compteur - > value);
    compteur = compteur - > next;
  }
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/uUNhcMI
thank you for answering
this is what i get after i edited that

Comment: @HaythemTarchouna is that what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Under condition `if (head==NULL){` you are not doing the assignment

```
 temp->value=val;
```

Hence, for first element value could be garbage.